# RXJS + Axios stagger network requests

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs, axios

I'm working with an API that has very strict rate limits and I need to send a number of requests to the same endpoint from names in an array. I set up a simple demo project and I tried this (and may variants of):

```
const pokemon = ['ditto', 'bulbasaur', 'charizard', 'pikachu'];
const obs = pokemon.map((pk, index) => {
  return from(axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pk}`)).pipe(delay(1000),map(res => {
    return {id: res.data.id, name: res.data.name, height: res.data.height};
  }));
});

concat(obs).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

but the `Axios.get()`'s all fire off when they are created and the `concat().subscribe()` just logs 4 observables. If I subscribe to the `from().pipe()` then after a second all 4 logout at once but then I'm subscribing in a subscribe which is poor.

The solution I settled on feels so cumbersome I have to believe there is a better way:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const { forkJoin, from } = require('rxjs');
const { map } = require('rxjs/operators');

const pokemon = ['ditto', 'bulbasaur', 'charizard', 'pikachu'];

const obs = pokemon.map((pk, index) => {
  return from(new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(async () => {
    const prom = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pk}`);
    resolve(prom);
  }, index*1000))).pipe(map(res => {
    console.log('fetched: ', pk);
    return {id: res.data.id, name: res.data.name, height: res.data.height};
  }))
})

forkJoin(obs).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

This delays the creation of the `axios.get()`, if I run with `node --require debugging-aid/network rxjs_axios_delay.js` I can see the delayed network requests and the real API I am hitting is happy, but this feels complicated and not very "RXy".

Anyone got anything better?

Comment: If the code is working then this is a https://codereview.stackexchange.com question.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 sorry, didn't know that one existed

Comment: Can be achieved very simply with a well documented pattern involving Array.prototype.reduce() and promisified timeouts. Observables make it unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: great! have you got a link to that documentation? For clarification this is part of a larger project making user of RxJS and happen mid pipe hence using observables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the Axios.get()'s all fire off when they are created

this highlights a *very interesting* trait of Promises: they are **eager**. I think the `defer` operator can come in handy:

```js
const pokemon = ['ditto', 'bulbasaur', 'charizard', 'pikachu'];

const obs = pokemon.map((pk, index) => {
  return defer(() => axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pk}`)).pipe(delay(1000),map(res => {
    return {id: res.data.id, name: res.data.name, height: res.data.height};
  }));
});

concat(...obs).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-concat-spread-obs?file=index.ts).

The cool thing about `defer` is that it evaluates the given expression(i.e invokes the callback function) when it is being subscribed to.
This means you could also do things like these:

```js
let dep$ = of('A');
const src$ = defer(() => dep$);

if (someCondition) {
  dep$ = of('B')
}

// if `someCondition` is true, `dep$` will be `of('B')`
src$.pipe(...).subscribe()
```

Comment: Sadly not, for concat all you get is a log of the observables, if you forkJoin or combineLatest on it then they all fire off at the same time. I've gotten close with interval(1000) and .zip which also works but gives me discrete emitted outputs and not a single array

Comment: @SimonBarker `concat(...obs)` should give the actual values. Updated the answer with a SB demo.

Comment: i always forget concat needs a spread, thanks!

Comment: Now just to workout how to map them to a single array rather than discrete outputs

Comment: @SimonBarker didn't know about that until now! For the second part, I think you can do something like: `concat(...).pipe(toArray()).subscribe(...)`.

Comment: no worries! yep that works nicely, had just found that method and can confirm it works. this is much better, feels a lot more "RX-y"